# Error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘for’ in #define

Tags: c++, c, compilation

I have an error in a #define in which I want to define a loop in this way:

```
#define loop                for (;;)
```

But at compiling time I get the error

`util.h:39:29: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘for’
 #define loop                for (;;)`

Any idea why this can be?

Comment: Please show the invocation of the macro

Comment: I'm just putting this out there, but this macro is probably a terrible idea.

Comment: @chris - There is no probably involved. It is a ....... idea

Comment: Is there any non-space whitespace *between* the macro body and the definition? I would *not* expect to see that error message *in* a macro definition ..

Comment: @EdHeal, I would say so, but next thing you know, there will be some good reason pulled out of nowhere that never crossed my mind and then my comment will no longer be accurate :)

Comment: What is on the lines before the macro definition?  Is line 39 of util.h the macro definition or something that uses it?

Comment: I can compile #define loop for(;;) without error using g++ with Geany, what compiler are you using?

Comment: @chris - lack of job security?

Comment: @EdHeal, Heh, maybe. Never hurts to allow for unforseen possibilities. Except when it does...

Comment: Years ago, when I was first learning C, I wrote `#define EVER ;;` ... `for (EVER)`. At the time, I thought it was very clever. I still think it's very clever. I just no longer think that's a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't contain enough information to find the problem. The problem is likely a collision with something else, probably another `#define`, in your code. The error message itself indicates that the compiler thinks it's parsing an argument list declaration when it reads the `for` token.

You'd need to post a small, complete, stand-alone program that demonstrates the problem.

---

Seriously, everyone who discovers `#define` in C programming class thinks that they're really clever and can now make their own language constructs out of it. In every case, that's a really bad idea, because it makes the code much more difficult to read with zero real benefit. If you need an infinite loop,just write out `for(;;)` and be done with it.

Comment: you where right, it was a collision with another #define :)

Comment: Another reason not to write macros like that. Did I mention that C++ is doing all it can to keep you from ever needing `#define`?

Comment: no you didn't but it's useful to know .. really I was just compiling the bitcoin source on my machine and it kept giving me an error in that specific #define . thank you

Comment: And they expect us to trust wealth to code like that. Kind of amazing.

Answer (score 1):

I think the below link will do the work for u..
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/lounge/33524/

Comment: Those macros make me cringe. Any of the potentially useful ones can be done just as good with functions, except not introduce a global name that you can never use again.

Comment: thank you, really useful source :) .. but I already found the problem, it was a collision with another #define